# Parenthesization that minimize values of an expression

Tags: dynamic-programming

I need to find a parenthesization for `E= c1 O1 c2 O2 .... On-1` `cn` where `c(i)` are integers and `O(i)` could be `+` or `*`, that minimize the obtainable value through a parenthesization.

I know that's probably a very basic question, but I just started learning Dynamic Programming.

My main problem is how can I distinguish if `O(i)` is `+` or `*` (or is this useless ? )

Comment: Same question except minimize <-> maximize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025234/algorithm-to-bracket-an-expression-in-order-to-maximize-its-value

Comment: Oh thanks! I was sure I searched for it, never mind, thank you again!