# Bracket distribution algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have encountered a peculiar situation with the bracket distribution problem.

The task is to find the maximum value of **a1 o a2 o a3 o ... aN**, where o is an operand that is **2*a+3*b**. None of the standard algorithms seem to provide the answer I'm looking for.

I have tried using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025234/algorithm-to-bracket-an-expression-in-order-to-maximize-its-value) but without success. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please explain what is peculiar about that operator and why, precisely, the DP solution proposed in the linked question fails to meet your expectations. As written, your question is far too vague.

Comment: The limits for N and a_i are irellevant, I just need a general solution.

Comment: The issue with that solution is that it always has same a_i's whereas in my example a_i's change depending on their side in the operation, whether by being multiplied by 2 or by 3.

Comment: The linked-to solution is completely general. It applies to any binary operation (or list of binary operations), including yours.

Comment: @ivankukic: the problem does not allow reordering, so the fact that an operator is not commutative is not relevant. It "merely" needs to be monotonic. Any bracketing will have a_i (or the expression which includes it) on the left of a_{i+1} (ditto).